# How to use browser bookmarks more securely?

Tags: linux, privacy, firefox, surveillance

I have been wondering in how far any tracking sites or other instances could gather information about me through my browser bookmarks (ie. in Firefox). An online search did not result in a lot of information about this. However, a few sites mentioned that bookmarks in combination with other information could actually give away a lot about me, my interests, my browsing behavior etc... e.g. [this site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/browser-compromises-privacy/) states that: "If someone knows that you use Bank of America and your email address, they would be one password theft away from breaking in." While I'm not so much afraid of hackers, I'm deeply concerned about being tracked all of the time and would like to minimize the information certain companies are stealing from me on a daily basis...

#### My Questions:

- In how far can especially *the big 5* (Google, Amazon etc) but also other instances track me through my bookmarks?
- How can I resolve that situation? How can I protect myself against that?

So, is this really a problem? If yes, I would prefer to have a solution without having to resign from bookmarks altogether. I rather have an encrypted, offline bookmark manager or something... (if there is something like this?). I'm not using any syncing whatsoever but maybe this is also a thing for other people interested in this.

I'm using a Linux machine (Arch-based) and browse in Firefox with many of these anti-tracking add-ons.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking or implying. If your bookmarks are local these companies don't have access to these, so they cannot use them to track you. If they are connected with the account (like when syncing using a Google account) the company obviously knows already that you are the same person since you are logged into a specific account, so there is no need for additional tracking based on the bookmarks.

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to know! The problem for me is rather: If tracking services can use my browser history etc, why cannot they also use my bookmarks? But you say I don't have to worry about it, correct? (as long as I'm not syncing of course)

Comment: Tracking services have no direct access to your browsing history either. But if they are included in a site you've visited then they know that you have visited this site. And since major tracking and ad services are included in the majority of web sites, they can track what you visit on the internet.